# How to install x32 abi support on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, architecture

As I m switching distribution, this question is an extension of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54301847) for getting maximum performance from a cpu hungry program which can t handle 64 bits pointers.

Because the problem isn t just about using the required binutils and compilers.

It also requires libraries like glibc. And so far, not packages contains x32.

Answer (score 0):

The `x32 ABI` is **not** supported by Fedora in any shape or form. No kernel support, no user space support. You're completely on your own.

---

If you're talking about `i386/i686` then unlike Debian you don't have to enable anything, you just go and install the required i686 package or library:

`dnf install package-name.i686`

All the dependencies will be installed automatically. `gcc` in Fedora is able to compile `i686` binaries out of the box and no `i686` version of it exists however if you're going to compile something which depends on libstdc++ you might have to install `libgcc.i686`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he is **not** talking about x32 which almost no distro supports.

Comment: Debian does ;-). And Ubuntu has `i386` enabled by default.

Comment: Let's wait for comments then :-)

Comment: @StephenKitt But what about `dpkg --add-architecture i386` for Debian/Ubuntu which the Internet is full of? No longer necessary?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes. I m talking about the x32 abi with 15 general purpose registers instead of 8 on plain 32 bits. Yes, I m coming from the Debian world where packages have the `x32` suffix.

Comment: The `x32 ABI` is not supported at all by Fedora.

Comment: @Artem that’s necessary on Debian but not on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, will try to remember that.

Comment: (I’m checking on 20.04 just to be sure...)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov are you sure? I didn t find anything about this on Fedora.

Comment: @user2284570 yes, Fedora doesn’t support x32; the kernels are built with `CONFIG_X86_X32` not set, and there’s no toolchain support.

Comment: @Artem I just checked on a new x86_64 Ubuntu 20.04 installation, `i386` is still included as a foreign architecture by default.

Comment: If only I knew what your comment means :-) A "foreign" arch? Is it enabled/disabled by default? ;-)